# How to insert a date in MySQL database using Java?

Tags: java

I have given date type and timestamp data type (4/2/2015 3:10:36 PM) also but I am getting below error. This date I am calling from XLSX sheet.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '4/2/2015 3:10:36 PM' for column 'date' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at com.tasc.xls.SearchExcel.main(SearchExcel.java:64)
```

Comment: Show us your Java code.

Comment: Are you using a `PreparedStatement` with a placeholder? You should be doing something like `statement.setDate(1, dateObj);`. If you set it as a string (looks like you are and not parsing it), it's not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably passing the date as a string in your prepared statement instead of passing it as a `Date` type. Passing it as a date type will send correctly your date to mysql.

Example:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE my_table set my_date = ?");
pstmt.setDate(1, yourDateConvertedIntoDateType);
```